# Dynamic Programming with Scala

Tags: python, algorithm, scala, dynamic-programming

To practice Scala I wanted do solve simple dynamic programming exercises with Scala. For some exercises I already wrote a Python implementation. Using Python most of the time I saved the intermediate results in an array.

For example this Exercise:

The algorithm outputs the minimal amount of coins needed to reach a value, given the value and a list of coins. (Assuming there is an unlimited amount of coins.)

```
def automat(n, coins = [1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200]):
    A = [0]
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        smallest_change = min([A[i - coin] for coin in coins if 0 <= i - coin])
        A.append(smallest_change + 1)
    return A[n]
```

Looks very simple in Python. Nevertheless I have problems writing the same code in Scala. Because of the functional paradigm I did not want to use a for-loop, but rather a tail-recursive algorithm to solve that problem. And I couldn't find any good solution. Maybe a tail-recursive algorithm is not the right way to go and there is a different scala-way to implement this simple algorithm.

I already looked for scala implementation of dynamic programming exercises and couldn't find a good source yet. Has someone an idea what the scala way to implement this would look like?

**UPDATE:**

The closest I came so far is very similar to Dimas tail-recursive approach. It looks like this

```
def automat(n: Int, coins: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200)): Int = {
    inner(n, n + 1, coins, List(0)).last
}

def inner(n: Int, m: Int, coins: List[Int], result: List[Int]): List[Int] = n match {
    case 0 => result
    case _ => inner(n-1, m, coins, result ::: List(coins.collect { case coin if (0 <= m - n - coin) => result(m - n - coin) }.min + 1))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more or less literal translation of your algorithm into idiomatic scala. The common idea in implementations like this is to replace loops updating mutable state sequentially with recursion, that passes state updates down as function arguments, and up as return values:

```
   def automat(n: Int, coins: Seq[Int] = Seq(1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200)): Array[Int] = n match {
     case 0 => Array(0)
     case n => 
       val out = automat(n-1, coins)
       val num = coins
         .collect { case coin if coin <= n  =>  out(n - coin) } 
         .min + 1
       out :+ num
   }
```

A better approach is to reverse the direction of the recursion, so that the algorithm can be implemented as a *tail-recursive* function, that removes the possibility of stack overflow with very large `n`:

```
  @tailrec
  def automat2(
    max: Int, 
    coins: Seq[Int] = Seq(1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200), 
    n: Int = 1, 
    out: Array[Int] = Array(0)
  ): Array[Int] = n match {
    case n if n > max => out
    case n => 
      val num = coins
        .collect { case coin if coin <= n  =>  out(n - coin) } 
        .min + 1
      automat2(max, coins, n+1, out :+ num)
  }
```

Of course, if you didn't want to stick to the particular algorithm you have been using, and were willing instead to settle on another approach, you could then have a much simpler solution like this:

```
@tailrec
def automat3(n: Int, coins: List[Int] = List(200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1), result: Int = 0): Int = (n, coins) match { 
   case (0, _) => result
   case (n, Nil) => 0
   case (n, head::tail) if head > n => automat3(n, tail, result)
   case (n, head::_) => automat3(n - head, coins, result+1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will take a closer look at the second tail-recursive approach. I was hoping for something like this! I think the third algorithm is not quite right, it seams like a greedy algorithm which always subtract the biggest coin value. This might work with the default coins, but there are examples for which this will fail.

Comment: @Lando-L you are right about greedy algorithm. I wonder what is the condition for the set of coins that is required for it to work. Any idea?

Comment: No unfortunately I don't know for which coin values a greedy algorithm works. I just know there are examples for which a greedy algorithm fails.

Comment: Last (greedy) solution is not correct.
Example:
`automat3(7, List(5, 4, 3, 1))` returns 3 (5 + 1 + 1), while it should be 2 (3 + 4)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that :

```
 def automat(n: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = (n, coins) match {
         case (0, _) => 1
         case (m, _) if m < 0 => 0
         case (_, cs)  if cs.isEmpty => 0
         case (m, cs) => automat(m - cs.head, cs) + automat(m, cs.tail) 
    }
```

If you are interested in Scala, the Coursera [class](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1) of Martin Odersky is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have a tail-recursive version for that approach? I had a similar solution already done, but this recursion explodes exponentially because of the two recursive calls. Small improve: you could write `case (_, Nil)` instead of `(_, cs) if cs.isEmpty`.

Comment: I'm not aware of (and I'm not sure there exists) an easy tail-recursive version. Except maybe if you use memoization. But it may be very memory-consuming.

Comment: Is memorization explained in the Coursera class or do you have a different source for memorization? The algorithm would simply need to memorize all solution for (0,..., n-1) to calculate the result for n, instead of calculating the same results over and over again.

Comment: I don't remember having seen memoization in the Coursera class, yet the wiki page is quite extensive on that subject. But don't forget that there is a tradeoff between memory usage and CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one version that I remember doing for one of the Scala couse

```
def minCoins(amount: Int, coins: Seq[Int]): Int =
  if (amount < 0) 0
  else if (coins.isEmpty) if (amount == 0) 1 else 0
  else
    minCoins(amount, coins.tail) + minCoins(amount - coins.head, coins)
```

So what you basically do is to have some combinations first by subtracting the amount from the Set of given coins and concatenating the combinations of the rest of the coins in the Set of given coins.